# Multivariate graph dataset

Tags: graph, neo4j, dataset, analytics

I'm searching for a good, interesting and freely available graph dataset that has the following properties:

1) nodes with properties of different data types (e.g. node.name = string, node.age = int, node.whatssoever = float) 
2) edges/relationships WITH properties of different types (edge.createdAt = date, edge.count = number, edge.type = category)

Best case is a format that can be directly imported into neo4j and/or viewed in Gephi.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has nobody an idea??

Answer (score 0):

Visit the [Example Datasets](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/) page for information on how to locate a large number of example datasets.